# Symfony search-box issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, search-box

I've an issue to make a search-box with Symfony and Doctrine. I use the 2.8 version of Symfony.

My issue is :

> EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given. 500 Internal Server Error - ORMInvalidArgumentException

So, this is my Type for my search-box type :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  {

    $builder->add('searchBox',SearchType::class,array('label'=>'Vous cherchez : Un auteur ? Un éditeur ? Un ouvrage ?','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class1' => 'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Ouvrages',
        'data_class2' => 'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Auteurs',
        'data_class3' => 'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Editeurs'
    ));
}
```

And this is my controller code after edit :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $ouvragesVentes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Ouvrages')->getOuvragesVentes();
    $ouvragesEchanges = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Ouvrages')->getOuvragesEchanges();
    $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Categories')->getAllCats();

    $form = $this->createForm(SearchBoxType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $searchBoxValue = $form->getData();

        $bookName = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Ouvrages')->getOuvrageName($searchBoxValue);
        $editorName = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Editeurs')->getEditeurName($searchBoxValue);
        $autorName = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Auteurs')->getAuteurName($searchBoxValue);

        //if author
        if ($searchBoxValue == $autorName){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sb_main_auteur'));
        }
        //if editor
        if ($searchBoxValue == $editorName){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sb_main_editeur'));
        }
        //if book name
        if ($searchBoxValue == $bookName){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sb_main_ouvrage'));
        }
    }

    $datas = array('categories'=>$categories,'form'=>$form->createView(),'ouvragesEchanges'=>$ouvragesEchanges,'ouvragesVentes'=>$ouvragesVentes);
    return $this->render('SBMainBundle:Main:index.html.twig',$datas);
}
```

Edit : My formHandler

```
    protected $request;
protected $form;
protected $em;


//faire une injection de dépendance avec Request,Manager,Form(Objet)
public function __construct(Request $request,EntityManager $em, Form $form){
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->form = $form;
}

//vérifie si le formulaire est soumis et valide
public function process(){

    if ($this->request->getMethod() == "POST"){
        //récupération des données de la requête de la superglobale $_POST
        $this->form->handleRequest($this->request);
        //si ok, on appel onSuccess()
        if ($this->form->isValid()){
            $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

//si formulaire soumis et valide, on presiste l'objet (enregistre dans la DB)
public function onSuccess($object){
    //on persiste dans la DB via le manager Doctrine
    $this->em->persist($object);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I've look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681531/symfony2-entitymanagerpersist-expects-parameter-1-to-be-an-entity-object-arr) but I think is not the solution of my issue. Then, someone can tell me what is wrong ? Do I need a search-box entity even with a search-box ?

Thanks for your help !

Edit :

Stack Trace

```
in src\SB\MainBundle\Repository\OuvragesRepository.php at line 130   -

public function getOuvrageName($titre){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        "SELECT o FROM SBMainBundle:Ouvrages o WHERE o.titreOuvrage = $titre ORDER BY o.id DESC "
    );
    return $query->getResult();


at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('8', 'Array to string conversion',     'C:\wamp\www\switchbook\src\SB\MainBundle\Repository\OuvragesRepository.php', '130', array('titre' => array('searchBox' => 'flammarion'))) 
in src\SB\MainBundle\Repository\OuvragesRepository.php at line 130   +
at OuvragesRepository ->getOuvrageName (array('searchBox' => 'flammarion')) 
in src\SB\MainBundle\Controller\MainController.php at line 35   +
at MainController ->indexAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(MainController), 'indexAction'),   array(object(Request))) 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 144   +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
```

in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 64   +
    at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69   +
    at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php     at line 185   +
    at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
    in web\app_dev.php at line 28   +

New Edit :

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("titreOuvrage") to generate a URL for route "sb_main_ouvrage".

```
sb_main_ouvrage:
path:     /ouvrage/{titreOuvrage}
defaults: { _controller: SBMainBundle:Main:ouvrage}
```

Stack Trace

in app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 911

```
$variables = array_flip($variables);
$mergedParams = array_replace($defaults, $this->context->getParameters(), $parameters);
if ($diff = array_diff_key($variables, $mergedParams)) {throw new MissingMandatoryParametersException(sprintf('Some mandatory parameters are missing ("%s") to generate a URL for route "%s".', implode('", "', array_keys($diff)), $name));}
$url ='';
$optional = true;

at UrlGenerator ->doGenerate (array('titreOuvrage'), array('_controller' => 'SB\MainBundle\Controller\MainController::ouvrageAction'), array(), array(array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'titreOuvrage'), array('text', '/ouvrage')), array(), 'sb_main_ouvrage', '1', array(), array()) 
in app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php at line 92   +
at appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator ->generate ('sb_main_ouvrage', array(), '1') 
in app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 1286   +
at Router ->generate ('sb_main_ouvrage', array(), '1') 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php at line 52   +
at Controller ->generateUrl ('sb_main_ouvrage') 
in src\SB\MainBundle\Controller\MainController.php at line 49   +
at MainController ->indexAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(MainController), 'indexAction'), array(object(Request))) 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 144   +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 64   +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69   +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php at line 185   +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in web\app_dev.php at line 28
```

And my controller for the mapping page :

```
    public function ouvrageAction(Ouvrages $ouvrages){
    $ouvrage =  $ouvrages->getTitreOuvrage();
    $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Categories')->getAllCats();
    $ouvragesVentes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Ouvrages')->getOuvragesVentesByName($ouvrage);
    $ouvragesEchanges = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SBMainBundle:Ouvrages')->getOuvragesEchangesByName($ouvrage);
    $datas = array('ouvragesVentes'=>$ouvragesVentes,'ouvragesEchanges'=>$ouvragesEchanges,'categories'=>$categories,'ouvrages'=>$ouvrages);
    return $this->render('SBMainBundle:Main:ouvrage.html.twig',$datas);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have the code of your FormHandler, the error may come from there. Your error talk about a persist() call but I see none in your code.

Comment: I add my formHandler, but I need it for many form for my ap. Do need I make a new one for my search-box ?

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no entity (or multiple) which means your $form->getData() will return an array. And, as the error says, you cannot pass an array to the persist() method.

If your goal is to save each search sent in your db you need to create an entity SearchBox (or whatever you want to call it), and set the data_class accordingly.

If you don't want to store the search then, you won't need to call your handler. (because it does nothing except call a persist()) 
And you don't need an entity, [check how to handle the submit without data_class](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/without_class.html)

Btw. in your handler you call $form->isValid() without $form->isSubmitted() and this code

```
if ($formHandler->process()){
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(''));
}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
// You will never come here, because $formHandler->process() will return true if your form is valid, and leave your indexAction
}
```

Hope it may helps you.

**Edit**

The data you pass to your repository is

```
$searchBoxValue = $form->getData();
```

This will return mark `searchBoxValue` as an array, because you ask for all the form data.

But what you want is to get the specific search field data, you need to do

```
$searchBoxValue = $form->get('searchBox')->getData();
```

Note that I would recommend to use a queryBuilder, or at least protect your query against sql injections.

e.g

```
public function getOuvrageName($titre){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        "SELECT o FROM SBMainBundle:Ouvrages o WHERE o.titreOuvrage = :titre ORDER BY o.id DESC "
    )
    ->setParameter('titre', $titre);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I try your solution, and I've a new issue : 
**An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT o0_.is_delete AS is_delete0, [...] FROM ouvrages o0_ WHERE o0_.titre_ouvrage = ?' with params ["lombres"]:
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**. I looking for on google but anything solve my issue.

Comment: You may want to show us the code of your select methods, I think you have a stacktrace who can tell you in which method there is the bug (or at least which one is invalid) and add the code of this method in your question.

Comment: I can show you my requests for looking for in my database, maybe it's help you to understand my issue.

Comment: For me the problem is in the method `getOuvrageName` of your repository. We need to see some code to help you.

Comment: My code  : `    public function getOuvrageName($searchBoxValue){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')->where('o.titreOuvrage = :searchBoxValue')
                                                ->setParameter('searchBoxValue',$searchBoxValue);
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }`

Comment: Well this code seems to be fine, my bad 100%. Do you have any stacktrace or any idea in which method the bug is? If yes add those informations in your question

Comment: I'd change my request :
public function getOuvrageName($titre){
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            "SELECT o FROM SBMainBundle:Ouvrages o WHERE o.titreOuvrage = $titre ORDER BY o.id DESC " //requete en DQL proche du SQL, 1ere partie
        );

        return $query->getResult();

    }

Then i've this issue : **Notice: Array to string conversion**

Comment: Please add, the method who crashes in your question, it will be easier to solve.

Comment: I've made an edit with my stacktrace. I hope it's helping you !

Comment: I'ts work ! But I've a new issue now with my route. I modify my post so that you take a look.

Comment: This is a brand new problem, you need to check the calls of the route `sb_main_ouvrage`, do they all have the `titreOuvrage` argument set? It is a more common issue, you'll be able to find some thread about this error message, on SO or on google :-)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for all, I solve my issues. I'm realy greatful for your help !!! In deed it's the 'titreOuvrage' argument missing in my routing.